# Round the number

Tags: google-sheets

Hello How I can round that number without using custom formats like this "[>999999]0.0,,\M;[>999]0.0,\K;0"
[image: 1]

Because if y use the custom format with this formula '="EXAMPLE "&E24' puts the value without that format.

[image: 2]

Comment: `="EXAMPLE"&convert(A3;"g";"kg")&"K"`, will give `EXAMPLE77,7K`. If you add the proper rounding, you should be able to get `EXAMPLE 77K`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
="example "&IF(A1<1000, A1,
 IF(A1<1000000,       TEXT(A1/1000,          "#.0")&"K",
 IF(A1<1000000000,    TEXT(A1/1000000,       "#.0")&"M",
 IF(A1<1000000000000, TEXT(A1/1000000000,    "#.0")&"B", 
                      TEXT(A1/1000000000000, "#.0")&"T"))))
```

[image]