# Excel: How to add two numbers that has unit prefixes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to add numbers that have the unit prefixes appended at the end (mili, micro, nano, pico, etc). For example, we have these two columns below:

[image]

Obviously doing something like `=A2+A3+A4` and `=B2+B3+B4` would not work. How would you resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Is there a finite set of units/unit prefixes your solution needs to support?

Comment: Needs more details. What is the expected output for the data you provided?

Comment: Do you want the units converted? Column 1 without unit conversion would be 721.203 + 1.368 + 119.551, but with units conversion (all into ms) it would be 721.203 + 0.001368 + 0.119551.  It would be odd to add these numbers without converting to a common unit, but that is all the posted answers have shown so far.

Comment: @Marc The miliseconds (ms) and microseconds (us)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes, I would like them converted to account for the difference in units, to get an accurate addition

Comment: @BigBen the output can be shown in any units (but preferably miliseconds to make it more clean)

Comment: These units belong in a custom number format... not in the value itself.

Comment: @mathieuGuindon how would you then sum them the proper way?

Comment: @P.b and how do you sum them when they're text?

Comment: @P.b nice, I knew there'd be some formula from hell leveraging all the crazy Turing-complete new capabilities that could do it - my point was that the units are metadata that is separate from the values. If you want to show "25ms" in a cell and do any kind of math with it, you enter 25 and format it to append "ms". In this case you'd insert helper columns for N1 & N2 where you'd extract the units and values, and then another one to convert it all into the same unit, and sum up that column.

Comment: Instead you can **substitute** the **right** 2 characters & convert them to numbers, then you can easily add it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the initial TEXTSPLIT solution does exactly that: splitting the value and the text and multiplying the value based on the unit. Instead of using helper cells it used helper names inside LET.

Comment: And it only works if your Excel supports dynamic arrays and LET and all the crazy new stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't have excel version constraints, per the tags listed in your question. Put all the suffixes as delimiters inside `{}` delimited by a comma as follow in `TEXTSPLIT`, then define the conversion rules in `XLOOKUP`. We use `SUBSTITUTE(col, nums, "")` as input of `XLOOKUP` to extract the unit of measure.

```
=BYCOL(A2:B4, LAMBDA(col, LET(nums, 1*TEXTSPLIT(col,{"ms","us"},,1),
 units, XLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(col, nums, ""), {"us";"ms"},{1;1000}),
 SUM(nums * units))))
```

The above formula converts the result to a common unit of microseconds (`us`), i.e. to the lower unit, so milliseconds get converted by multiplying by `1000`. If the unit of measure was not found it returns `#N/A`, it can be customized by adding a fourth parameter to `XLOOKUP`. If you want the result in milliseconds, then replace: `{1;1000}` with `{0.001;1}` or `VSTACK(10^-3;1)` for example.

[image: excel output1]

If you would like to have everything in seconds, you can use the trick of using power combined with the `XMATCH` index position, to generate the multiplier. I took the idea from this question: [How to convert K, M, B formatted strings to plain numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73550366/how-to-convert-k-m-b-formatted-strings-to-plain-numbers), check the answer from @pgSystemTester (for Gsheet, but it can be adapted to Excel). I included nanoseconds too.

```
=BYCOL(A2:B4,LAMBDA(col,LET(nums,1*TEXTSPLIT(col,{"ms","us"},,1),
  units, 1000^(-IFERROR(XMATCH(RIGHT(col,2), {"ms";"us";"ns"}),0)),
  SUM(nums * units))))
```

Under this approach, seconds is the output unit, because it is not part of the `XMATCH` `lookup_array` input argument, the multiplier will be `1` (as a result of `1000^0`), so no units or seconds (`s`) will be treated the same way.

**Notes**:

- In my initial version I used `INDEX`, but as @P.b pointed out in the comments, it is not really necessary to remove the second empty column, instead, we can use the `ignore_empty` input argument from `TEXTSPLIT`. Thanks
- You can use `TEXTBEFORE` instead of `TEXTSPLIT`, as follows: `TEXTBEFORE(A2:A4,{"ms","us"})`

Comment: I was assuming the solution needed to account for adding  differing units, e.g. microseconds + milliseconds, based on the unit specified. Does yours do that?

Comment: @BigBen, true, but original poster mentioned adding the column values, e.g., `=A2+A3+A4`.

Comment: Ah good point. Either way, needs more detail.

Comment: @Marc I was trying to respond to the ask about adding numbers with suffixes, having a way to remove them and to sum it. The OP mentions different units, but no indication of any conversion mapping to consider. Let's see if the OP provides more clarity around that. At least here it covers how to remove the suffix and do some operation. Thanks

Comment: Why is INDEX used?

Comment: @P.b true we can use the ignore_empty from `TEXTSPLIT`. I will update it, thanks

Comment: Hello @DavidLeal yes I would like them to be converted to account for the difference in units.

Comment: @tadm123 thanks for your clarification, please check my updated answer. It converts everything to the lower unit of measure (microseconds). I added also an approach for converting everything to seconds. I hope it helps

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks, can I have a formula to convert a single column instead of doing it both at the same time?

Comment: Since this formula only works with there's two columns in conjunction with each other..

Comment: yes, @tadm123 you can use the following and adjust the range via `rng` name value: `=LET(rng, A2:A4, nums, 1*TEXTSPLIT(rng,{"ms","us"},,1),units, XLOOKUP(RIGHT(rng,2), {"us";"ms"},{1;1000}), SUM(nums * units))`

Comment: I saw your last comment, there is no need to do it column by column, if the columns are separated, you can use the same approach, wrapping the `BYCOL` input with `CHOOSECOLS` for example: `=BYCOL(CHOOSECOLS(A2:Z4, 1,3,5,7), LAMBDA(col, LET(nums, 1*TEXTSPLIT(col,{"ms","us"},,1),
  units, XLOOKUP(RIGHT(col,2), {"us";"ms"},{1;1000}), SUM(nums * units))))`, but the result will be consecutive columns

Comment: One last question if you don't mind man, I already accepted your answer, how would you account if there's a "s"? (seconds) in the case of a single column.

Comment: @tadm123 I included this answer in my updated answer before, please take a look and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Borrowing from @DavidLeal, I tried this, which appears to work if the value, e.g., "75ms" appears in cell A1: `=1*TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"s","ms","us"},,1)*XLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A1,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"s","ms","us"},,1),""), {"s";"ms";"us"},{1;1000;1000000})`. BTW David, as an onlooker, I got an education here on some functions I haven't used, so thanks!

Comment: @Marc this is the approach I suggested too (similar maybe, but not the same, I am not sure), to remove `RIGHT` in case of having a unit of measure of a single character, but yes using `RIGHT` is more restrictive.